# Executing privileged Shell commands in Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

This is a simple code I made to allow executing of Shell commands:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RestController
public class ShellController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/shell", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response postFile(@RequestParam(value = "command") String command) {
        try {
            boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name")
                    .toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
            if (isWindows) {
                builder.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                builder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
            } else {
                builder.directory(new File(System.getenv("HOME")));
                builder.command("sh", "-c", command);
            }
            Process process = builder.start();
            StringConsumer consumer = new StringConsumer();
            StreamGobbler streamGobbler =
                    new StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), consumer);
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(streamGobbler);
//          int exitCode = process.waitFor();
//          assert exitCode == 0;
            if(process.waitFor(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                return new Response(0, consumer.getConsumed());

            }
            return new Response(-1, consumer.getConsumed());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Response(-1, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

The Windows OS execution of this program works fine, but it does not work right when running from a Linux OS, here's a sample endpoint:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8686/shell?command="ls"
```

The problem is that when running `mkdir` or even `rm` it does not work, my ultimate goal here is to

- Write file to a path that is restricted with sudo
- Remove file given the path (sudo)
- Execute command to start / stop server (e.g. `nginx -s reload`)

Comment: Beware: This is a horrible security vulnerability; it lets any web page take over your server.  At the very least, add CSRF protection, but you will still have bad security issues.

Comment: Yes I understand I will put security once it is working as expected.

Comment: So you are basically giving everybody who can reach your server remote code execution capabilities. This is a horrible security issue. If you want some remote management capabilities, you should restrict it to a set of predefined commands that are chosen by an identifier.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings not at all, we don't plan 'users' to use this, this is an interface between machines, or rather microservices, so one web server upon a trigger and user action will then call this resource to write/delete a file and/or other system functions.

Comment: "it does not work", add details please.

Comment: These ones worked for me on jshell: `builder.command("sh", "-c", "mkdir aaaa");`, `builder.command("sh", "-c", "touch aaaa; mv aaaa bbbb")`.